# Include intentionally pixelated graphics in document

Tags: graphics

I am trying to create a poster for a conference.  One element of my scientific data is a 12 pixel by 12 pixel image that I would like to display heavily "magnified".  In other words, I want it to be big.

It is critical, however, that the data be represented as truly as possible.

When I open the `.png` file in my typical image viewing software, it looks great.  The pixels are crisply distinguishable, as they should be.

When I include the `.png` file in my document with the following code, however, it blurs out completely and it misrepresents the data.

The raw 12 px by 12 px image is here:

[image]

The code is here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=4in,paperwidth=4in,margin=1in,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=10]{imgout.png}
\end{document}
```

The apparent output is here:

[image]

How do I include my image in the latex document without blurring?

Comment: Since `png` is a bitmap format, the image cannot be magnified arbitrarily like a vector image ('eps', 'pdf', etc.) You'll either need to create the image in vector format, or make the bitmap file much larger than 12 pixels.

Comment: If it's only 12x12 pixel you can try to draw the image manually using Tikz or you can try to convert it into a vector graphic using Inkscape for example: https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example? I have trouble recreating your issue. It could also be a viewer problem. Both acroread and evince aren't anti-aliasing png's here.

Comment: @TonioElGringo I've added a working example that is hopefully sufficient

Comment: Can't reproduce here. This is what I get when downloading your image and compiling your MWE with `pdflatex`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8L7VS.png

Comment: Voted unclear: the problem cannot be reproduced with the provided MWE and PNG file on an up-to-date TeX Live distribution.

Comment: Very likely the blurring comes from some kind of anti-aliasing setting of the PDF viewer. One way of solving it would be to replace the image pixels by a boxes of the same colors as the pixels.